# Is a bonus for a dedicated spell focus too powerful?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, spellcasting-focus

Would giving a bonus to spell casters via a dedicated spell focus make them too powerful?

Examples:

A dedicated focus for all evocation spells grants a +1 bonus to spell attack rolls and damage. A dedicated focus for all enchantment spells grants +1 to the spell save DC.

A +2 focus item will be more specific, i.e., only for fire spells or only for Wisdom spell saves.

A +3 bonus will target a particular spell, i.e., only works for Scorching Ray or only works for Charm Person.

Just as a fighter can have a +2 sword, +1 bow, +3 shield and +1 armor, with this idea a spell caster could have a +2 fire focus, +1 enchantment focus, +3 Charm Person focus and a +1 illusion focus. So it seems to me that this would not be unbalancing, but I'm new to DnD5e so I'm not sure if this would give spell casters too much power compared to other classes.

Comment: When submitting homebrew, please see the link to meta I gave to you in your earlier and nearly identical question. We really do need a fully fleshed out item along with the other information in that meta.

Comment: For future reference, we prefer questions be edited, rather than reposted. You can simply  [edit] the question to be its best possible (no need to mark the edit; there's a revision history built into the site). Though we'll make the exception and just move forward with this one.

Comment: What level of caster would these be given to? Do/will the other characters have +1 etc items? What kind of creatures or situations will the player(s) encounter and use these foci in?

Answer (score 1):

Items like [Wand of the War Mage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-the-war-mage) and [Rod of the Pact Keeper](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/rod-of-the-pact-keeper) already exist. So if these items would be too powerful depends entirely on their respective rarity (And the exact wording of the items, which you have not provided)

Keep in mind that unlike say a +1 longsword. If you wield two focus items, their wording may allow you to apply BOTH benefits to a spell. Meaning a +3 Rod of the Pact Keeper and +3 focus of charming would both increase your spell DC by 3. It is just something else you will need to keep your eyes on as a DM. Or add language stating it does not stack with similar effects in the magic items.

Answer (score 0):

### This would be fine*

As long as the rest of the system is respected, these seem like reasonable items - a +3 charm person focus is certainly less powerful than a +3 normal focus, for example, and so it cannot be overpowered.

As far as "the rest of the system", and my * from the title:  it is important to respect the systems in place, specifically things like bounded accuracy.  A +6 charm person focus becomes quite questionable, even if it might be overall less powerful than a standard +3 focus.